# Error( "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." Functional Component and doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my component :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Product = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return ( 
        <>
        <span className="m-2 text-info">Laptop</span>
        <span className="m-2 badge bg-primary">{format()}</span>
        <button onClick={increase()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
        <button onClick={decrease()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
        <button onClick={delet()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </> 
     );

     function increase(){
          setCount(count + 1);
      }
      
     function decrease(){
          setCount(count - 1);
      }
     function delet(){
          setCount(count - count);
      }
      
     function format(){
          if (count === 0){
              return "Zero";
          }else{
              return count;
          }
      }
}
 
export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the functions instead of passing them.

Change this

```
<button onClick={increase()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
<button onClick={decrease()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
<button onClick={delet()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Into this

```
 <button onClick={() => increase()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
 <button onClick={() => decrease()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
 <button onClick={() => delet()} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Or this

```
 <button onClick={increase} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
 <button onClick={decrease} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
 <button onClick={delet} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Also, little adivce, I would move the function declarations to the very top, and rendering part to the bottom.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Product = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
     function increase(){
          setCount(count + 1);
      }
      
     function decrease(){
          setCount(count - 1);
      }
     function delet(){
          setCount(count - count);
      }
      
     function format(){
          if (count === 0){
              return "Zero";
          }else{
              return count;
          }
      }
    return ( 
        <>
        <span className="m-2 text-info">Laptop</span>
        <span className="m-2 badge bg-primary">{format()}</span>
        <button onClick={increase} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
        <button onClick={decrease} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
        <button onClick={delet} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </> 
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change onClick functions to arrow function :

```
<button onClick={() => increase()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `onClick` trigger and also you have to reformat your functions as i see you have used functions after `return()`.

So the right code will be this:

```js
const Product = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


     function increase(){
          setCount(count + 1);
      }
      
     function decrease(){
          setCount(count - 1);
      }
     function delete(){
          setCount(count - count);
      }
      
     function format(){
          if (count === 0){
              return "Zero";
          }else{
              return count;
          }
      }

    return ( 
        <>
        <span className="m-2 text-info">Laptop</span>
        <span className="m-2 badge bg-primary">{format()}</span>
        <button onClick={() => {increase()}} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-success">+</button>
        <button onClick={() => {decrease()}} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-warning">-</button>
        <button onClick={() => {delete()}} className="m-2 btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </> 
     );
}
 
export default Product
```